# Applet runs on one computer, not the other, and not in applet-viewer

Tags: java, applet

I have a 3rd-party applet I have to use, and unfortunately - I don't have access to its code. Pointing Firefox to the applet works on one computer, but not on the other.

Both computers show a warning prior to running the applet (alas, the applet is not signed), but on the first one the applet is shown properly, and on the second only a gray rectangle is shown.

I tried using `appletviewer` to run the app, and it fails on both computers. It complains about an Access Denied exception, saying the `createClassLoader` permission is missing.

Here is how the app is embedded in the HTML:

```
<applet width="805" height="605" align="MIDDLE" 
    archive="tpinstaller-s.jar,eib-s.jar,eibbus-s.jar,libusb4j-s.jar,log4j-1.2.8-
             s.jar,xpp3_min-1.1.4c-s.jar,xstream-1.4.2-s.jar" 
    codebase="/applet/" 
    code="com.ttechgroup.cdinnovation.tp.objectcanvas.standalone.applet.
          TPApplet.class">
```

(I've added a couple of line breaks to make it fit. the `archive` and `code` attributes are one line each in the real HTML)

I would like to at least get the appletviewer to work, if possible.

Comment: You need to adjust the applet security policy file on the machine you are trying to run the applet on...

Comment: Where do I do that? And how do I change the HTML so that it works on all machines?

Comment: You can't change the HTML to make it work on all machines, it's the client machine that makes the determination, that's the point.  Take a look at [Set up a Policy File to Grant the Required Permission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html)

Comment: Thank, I'll take a look. If you turn this comment to an answer, I can accept it.